# While won't start loop after y/n input C++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Problem: `while` doesn't work to start loop over when user inputs `y`.

I have spent hours searching all forums including Stack Overflow for a clue and tried to figure this out (learning C++ on my own).  Based on what I have read I have tried: a `do` loop works when placed at beginning but it incorrectly calculates by multiplying prior `numb` entry by next entry factorial (flushing problem?), I tried `break` and it stops calculation but it also stops without getting to cout <<“Do another?”. I have also tried adding/moving braces around statements and if statements (in desperation).

```
//problem #6 page 127 Robert Lafore OOP Prg C++ 4th ed.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int numb;
    unsigned long fact = 1;  //long for larger numbers
    char ch;

    cout << "Enter a number  ";
    cin >> numb;

    for (int j = numb; j > 0; j--) //multiply 1 by
    {
        fact *= j;
        cout << "Factorial is "<< fact << endl;
        cout << "Do another? (y/n)\n";
        cin >> ch;
    }

    while(ch !='n');  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your logic isn't quite right - you need to perform the operation once, then ask, and redo the entire operation.

Right now, you do a `for` loop for your operation, then get the character the user types *every loop iteration*, then just start a `while` loop that never terminates.

`do/while` is a good candidate for this:

```
do
{
    fact = 1; // Reinitialize for subsequent loops
    cout << "Enter a number  ";
    cin >> numb;

    for(int j = numb; j > 0; j--) //multiply 1 by
    {
        fact *= j;
    }

    cout << "Factorial is " << fact << endl;
    cout << "Do another? (y/n)\n";
    cin >> ch;
 }
 while (ch == 'y');  // Switched to make anything other than 'y' break out
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same calculation error, e.g. If you enter 3, it will factor correctly to be 6. If you say y to do another and enter in 2, you get a result of 12 which is not a factor of 2, it is 2 times 6...how do I flush out previous inputs before entering a new input?

Comment: @AbigailShearer Did you leave in the `fact = 1;`  inside the do/while loop (as I have above?)  It sounds like that's missing

Comment: Arrrg.(redfaced) Nope. Now I did and it works, if I understand correctly the fact=1 is a way of setting it back? Thanks so much,I learned a lot on this one!

Comment: @AbigailShearer Yes, it's being set to 1 at the start of each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
do
{
    for(int j=numb; j>0; j--) //multiply 1 by
    {
        fact *=j;
    }
    cout <<"Factorial is "<< fact<<endl;
    cout <<"Do another? (y/n)\n";
    cin >> ch;
}
while (ch != 'n');
```

What's wrong:

Your code goes into a `for` loop:

```
for(int j=numb; j>0; j--)
```

It calculates the factorial...but the code to do another one is in the `for` loop! Your program flow is like this:

- Enter the `for` loop

  - Multiply `fact` by `j` and store the value in `fact`
  - Print the value of `fact`
  - Ask to do another

    - Store the value in `ch`
  - Continue the `for` loop

See the problem? You are asked to do another for each iteration of the `for` loop. Then, the `while` loop does this:

- Loop while `ch` isn't equal to `'n'`.

But...the loop is infinite! After the last iteration of the `for` loop, `ch` doesn't change. So, if the last value was `'y'`, well, the `while` loop keeps on looping over...and over...and over...since it has no body, it just continues forever.

Answer (score 0):

You have sort of the right bits of code, but the bits of code are in the wrong places.

1. Move the output and input for "Do Another" to after the for-loop.
2. Add `do {` before `cout << "enter a number`;`
3. Add '} `before`while(ch != 'n');`

Right now, you have a forever loop when `ch` is not `'n'`, since nothing changes `ch` inside the actual loop.